# Semi-continuity theorem and construction of Hilbert and Quot schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, flatness, coherent-sheaves

I am studying Nitsure's wonderful essay *[Construction of Hilbert and Quot schemes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504590)*, and I am stuck on page 21.

Given a Noetherian schemes $S$ and a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over $\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S}$, Nitsure constructs a finite set of locally closed and mutually disjoint subschemes $V_{i}$ ($i\in\left\{1,...,t\right\}$) so that $\mathcal{F}|_{V_{i}}$ is flat over $V_{i}$, and he concludes from this that there exists an integer $N_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall r\geq 1, m\geq N_{1}:R^{r}\pi_{*}\mathcal{F}(m)=0$, where $\pi:\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S}\longrightarrow S$ is the projection, and for every $s\in S$ one has $H^{r}(\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S},\mathsf{F}_{s}(m))=0$.

Furthermore, one can show that there exists an $r_{1}\geq N_{1}$ so that for any $m\geq r_{i}$ the map
\begin{equation*}
    (\pi_{*}\mathcal{F}(m))|_{V_{i}}\longrightarrow\pi_{i*}\mathcal{F}_{V_{i}}(m)
\end{equation*}
is an isomorphism.

So far, so good. Now the author proceeds to claim

> As the higher cohomologies of all fibers, in particular the first cohomology, vanish, it follows ***by semi-continuity theory*** for the flat family $\mathcal{F}_{V_{i}}$ over $V_{i}$ that for any $s\in V_{i}$ the base change homomorphism $(\pi_{i}\mathcal{F}_{V_{i}}(m))|_{s}\longrightarrow H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{n}_{s},\mathcal{F}_{s}(m))$ is an isomorphism for $m\geq r_{i}$.

First of all, I assume what the author really meant to write was *semi-continuity theor**em***. Secondly, I don't understand how that theorem implies Nitsure's claim.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One comment: the $V_i$ are locally closed subschemes (not open generally). Then the claim you're looking for should follow from Theorem 3.7 (3). (Or from the cohomology and base change theorem in Hartshorne -- Theorem III.12.11).

Comment: hmmmmmm..... why? I don't get it.